# Executing KeyDown method after pressing button

Tags: c#, button, keydown

Okay my last question wasn't really clear on things, so I deleted it and made this one.
I'm making the game 'snake'.
What I want is that AFTER I select a difficulty, the keydown on the form needs to work 
(you select a difficulty, the snake gets drawn and starts moving, in order for it to move to your preferred direction, you press the arrow keys)
Before I added the difficulties it worked perfectly.
Right now after I select the difficulty and want to play the game, the snake doesn't move, my keys don't react in the program.

So my problem = keyDown not working after selecting difficulty.

```
private void btnNormal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  timer1.Interval = 250;
  btnNormal.Visible = false;
  btnEasy.Visible = false;
  btnHard.Visible = false;
  diffLabel.Visible = false;
  timer1.Enabled = true;
  down = false;
  up = false;
  right = true;
  left = false;

}

private void btnHard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  timer1.Interval = 10;
  btnNormal.Visible = false;
  btnEasy.Visible = false;
  btnHard.Visible = false;
  diffLabel.Visible = false;
  timer1.Enabled = true;
  down = false;
  up = false;
  right = true;
  left = false;
}

private void btnEasy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  timer1.Interval = 500;
  btnNormal.Visible = false;
  btnEasy.Visible = false;
  btnHard.Visible = false;
  diffLabel.Visible = false;
  timer1.Enabled = true;
  down = false;
  up = false;
  right = true;
  left = false;
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

  if (e.KeyData == Keys.Down && up == false)
  {
    down = true;
    right = false;
    up = false;
    left = false;
  }

  if (e.KeyData == Keys.Up && down == false)
  {
    down = false;
    right = false;
    up = true;
    left = false;
  }

  if (e.KeyData == Keys.Right && left == false)
  {
    down = false;
    right = true;
    up = false;
    left = false;
  }

  if (e.KeyData == Keys.Left && right == false)
  {
    down = false;
    right = false;
    up = false;
    left = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: What were the default values of up, down, left, and right before you added the difficulty settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having all the code to test it, it is hard to pass a judgement...

However, my guess is that you added button to your form. In this case, if the button still has the focus, the KeyDown event isn't sent to the form, but to the button.

I would transform the Form1_KeyDown method to the override of the OnKeyDown base method and set PreviewKeys to true in the constructor.

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    KeyPreview = true;
}

protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Insert key presses logic
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```

Comment: This is correct and you might be right about the button still having the focus. Trying your method now.

Comment: Setting KeyPreview to true fixed the problem, however I'm unsure HOW/WHY it fixed my problem.. 
It would really help me if you explained why it works now.

Comment: From MS Description: "Gets or sets a value indicating whether the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus." Basically, if you don't set that, the event will go directly to the focused control and won't be passed to the form.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting property [`From.KeyPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx#Y0) to `true`.

From the link above, msdn says about this:

> true if the form will receive all key events; false if the currently
>   selected control on the form receives key events. The default is
>   false.
>
> When this property is set to true, the form will receive all KeyPress,
>   KeyDown, and KeyUp events. After the form's event handlers have
>   completed processing the keystroke, the keystroke is then assigned to
>   the control with focus. For example, if the KeyPreview property is set
>   to true and the currently selected control is a TextBox, after the
>   keystroke is handled by the event handlers of the form the TextBox
>   control will receive the key that was pressed.

In short your problem was of Focus. Your control that receives the KeyDown event may be not having focus. So we enforce the form to receive KeyDown event always, regardless whether the control receiving the event is focused or not.

Comment: Thanks, it works now! However I'm unsure HOW/WHY it fixed my problem.. It would really help me if you explained why it works now.